# Firefox extension not visible after installation

Tags: windows, firefox, firefox-extensions

I installed my Firefox extension in Firefox 6.1. It's showing "Firefox extension added successfully", but the extension is not visible in the toolbar.

It was working when I was working with Firefox 6.1 with Windows XP, but now I switched to Windows 7 Ultimate and now it's not visible. The add-on appears just beside the address bar, so maybe thats the problem.

I tried changing it from the Run → `%APPDATA%` → Mozilla → `*.default` file, but it shows no change.

Is the operating system creating the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on the address bar and go to ´customise´you may find the icon. You can then drag it onto the tool bar of choice. I´ve found that extensions don´t always install icons automatically.